# Haskell - getting Char type when expecting [Char] within List Monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I am practising Haskell by trying to make a program that finds .mp3 and .flac metadata and writes it neatly to a file. I've gone this far on my own but I am pretty stumped at what I should be doing. Here is the main chunk of the code here:

```
builddir xs = do
    writeto  <- lastest getArgs
    let folderl b = searchable <$> (getPermissions b)
    let filel   c = ((lastlookup mlookup c) &&) <$> ((not <$> folderl c))
    a <- listDirectory xs
    listdirs <- filterM (folderl) (map ((xs ++ "/") ++) a)
    filedirs <- filterM (filel)   (map ((xs ++ "/") ++) a)
    let tagfiles = mapM (tagsort) filedirs
    putStrLn $ concat listdirs
    putStrLn $ concat tagfiles


tagsort xs = do
    nsartist <- getTags xs artistGetter
    nsalbum  <- getTags xs albumGetter
    artist   <- init $ drop 8 $ show nsalbum
    album    <- init $ drop 7 $ show nsalbum
    (artist ++ " - " ++ album)
```

I know, it's very messy. When run in ghci, I get this:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Char’
• In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘artist’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: artist ++ " - " ++ album
  In the expression:
    do nsartist <- getTags xs artistGetter
       nsalbum <- getTags xs albumGetter
       artist <- init $ drop 8 $ show nsalbum
       album <- init $ drop 7 $ show nsalbum
       ....
       60    artist ++ " - " ++ album
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening. Running a similar command in a test program of mine:

```
main = do
artg <- getTags "/home/spilskinanke/backlogtest/02 - await rescue.mp3" artistGetter
let test = init $ drop 8 $ show artg
print test
```

this works exactly fine. Prints the string "65daysofstatic" to my terminal in ghci. It clearly is not a Char type. So why is being called a Char in my code?
Also note that before adding any pieces of code that referenced the metadata module I am using (htaglib) this program ran fine in a test. With the tagfiles function and tagsort monad absent, I was able to set an arg for a certain directory, and my test would successfully print a list of FilePaths containing all readable folders, and another list of FilePaths containing all files ending in whatever I desired in mlookup, in this case being .mp3, .mp4, .flac, and .wav. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will get much better error messages, and write much better questions, if you give every top-level definition a type signature. Also, when you're only giving a fragment of code please be sure to 1. Show your imports and 2. Give the type signatures of all the functions/values you wrote that are called/used in the fragment but not defined in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re mixing up `IO` and `[]` in `tagsort`:

```
tagsort xs = do

    -- Okay, run IO action and bind result to ‘nsartist’
    nsartist <- getTags xs artistGetter

    -- Similarly for ‘nsalbum’
    nsalbum  <- getTags xs albumGetter

    -- Mistaken: ‘init …’ returns a list, not an ‘IO’ action
    artist   <- init $ drop 8 $ show nsalbum
    album    <- init $ drop 7 $ show nsalbum

    -- You are also missing a ‘pure’ or ‘return’ here
    (artist ++ " - " ++ album)
```

The fixes are simple: use a `let` statement instead of a bind statement `<-`, and add a `pure` to make an `IO String` out of the `String` you have:

```
tagsort xs = do
    nsartist <- getTags xs artistGetter
    nsalbum  <- getTags xs albumGetter
    let artist = init $ drop 8 $ show nsalbum
    let album = init $ drop 7 $ show nsalbum
    pure (artist ++ " - " ++ album)
```

Generally speaking, each `do` block must be in a single monad, until you start learning about using monad transformers to combine different effects. So in an `IO` block, anything on the right of a binding statement must be an `IO` action; if you just want to do pure computations, you can use `let` (or just inline expressions, if you don’t need to bind something to a name). Finally, the last statement in a `do` block must also be an action in the particular monad—this is often a pure value, just wrapped up in the monad with `pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a` (or `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, which does the same thing but works in slightly fewer contexts because of the more restrictive `Monad` constraint).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Jon! I think it is time for me to take a break for a bit, as now I can clearly see that in my test program that worked I had in fact used a let binding, which I did not in my main block of code. Not sure how I missed that!

Comment: If I have another problem very related to this one, should I make an entirely new thread or simply ask it here?

Comment: @Sagarmatha New questions should be new questions.